# Saving data to Postgres DB using django rest framework

Tags: python, postgresql, api, web-services, django-rest-framework

I'm new in django development. I m developing an API in which i am sending data from client side (mobile app) and this data is to be stored in a database using django. And if I query the data the data should be fetched from the DB. Database is preferably postgres/mysql DB. I have written some part of the code but stuck how to proceed. I'll appreciate if someone can guide me how to proceed.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.http import Http404
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.core import serializers
from django.conf import settings
import json

# Create your views here. 
@api_view(["POST"])
def getIdealWeight(heightData): 
    try:
        height=json.loads(heightData.body)
        weight=str(height*10)
        return JsonResponse("the ideal weight is:"+weight+" kg.",safe=False) 
    except ValueError as e:                  
        return Response(e.args[0],status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the code, I'll advice you start from the very beginning of [DRF Tutorials](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) and cover a great part of it before going further with your project. After the quickstart, you should visit the individual parts dedicated to the major concepts like serializers, [views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/), etc. Jumping straight to the project without having a fair knowledge of the framework will make it difficult to achieve what you want.